# Cannot parse all the information of this website with a single loop

Tags: parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape this website

Scraping information is possible manually

However, I cannot access information within p...p tags and ul...ul tags with one loop. These two tags are in a similar division. However, the loop breaks whenever p replaces ul or vice-versa.
Is this possible with just one loop??

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
           "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
           "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
           "DNT":"1",
           "Connection":"close",
           "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1"}
source = requests.get('https://insights.blackcoffer.com/how-small-business-can-survive-the-coronavirus-crisis/',
                      headers=headers)
page = source.content
soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')
information = ''
for section in soup.find('div', class_='td-post-content').find_all('p'):
    if information != '':
        information = information + '\n' + section.text
    else:
        information = section.text
print(information)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
           "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
           "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
           "DNT":"1",
           "Connection":"close",
           "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1"}
source = requests.get('https://insights.blackcoffer.com/how-small-business-can-survive-the-coronavirus-crisis/',
                      headers=headers)
page = source.content
soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')
information = ''
for section in soup.find('div', class_='td-post-content').find_all(['p', 'li']):
    information += '\n\n' + section.text

print(information.strip())
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your effort. It is working fine.
However, the code should be soup.find('div', class_='td-post-content').find_all(['p', 'li']).
Otherwise, it is providing double text for 'ul' and 'li' inside 'ul'.

Comment: @Mr.Basu, good catch there. typo on my part